# Javascript - set onclick to only first section of page

Tags: javascript

I am developing this site: https://studioboom.superhi.com/

Is it possible to apply the image click to only the first section, so once scrolled you are able to click on links rather than add an image.

JS:

```
const images = [
  'benjones_flip1.jpg',
  'benjones_home1.jpg',
  'ben_jones_ts2.jpg',
  'benjones_gs1.jpg',
  'benjones_jt1.jpg',
  'benjones_dlf4.jpg'
]

let i = 0

function placeImage(x, y) {
  const nextImage = images[i]
  const img = document.createElement('img')

  img.classList.add('external-loaded-img')
  img.setAttribute('src', nextImage)
  img.style.left = x + 'px'
  img.style.top = y + 'px'

  document.body.appendChild(img)

  i = i + 1

  if (i >= images.length) {
    i = 0
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  placeImage(event.pageX, event.pageY)
})

document.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  placeImage(event.pageX, event.pageY)
})
```

```
.external-loaded-img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
  animation: fadein 0.5s;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Comment: Will you please include the html?

Comment: ^^ More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 0):

Either wait to set up your event handlers until the container of the elements you want them to apply to are present in the page, and then hook up the handlers on that container:

```
container.addEventListner('click', /*...*/);
container.addEventListner('touchend', /*...*/);
```

...or keep them hooked up on `document`, but check when the event occurs that it passed through that container ("event delegation"):

```
document.addEventListner('click', function(event) {
    if (!event.target.closest("selector-for-the-container")) {
        return;
    }
    // ...
});
document.addEventListner('touchend', /*...*/);
    if (!event.target.closest("selector-for-the-container")) {
        return;
    }
    // ...
});
```

More on `closest` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), including information about polyfills if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector(".about").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  placeImage(event.pageX, event.pageY)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this does work, if I am clicking on section.photo1, if I clicking on an actual image, it doesn't. Is there a work around for this?

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   if (!event.target.closest("section.photo1")) {
        return;
    }
event.preventDefault()
  placeImage(event.pageX, event.pageY)
})
```